# Cant upload multilple images using django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I have two models: one is the post model that can have multiple linked images. The image model has a foreign key to the post. That is, the images have a foreign key for a single post. When adding a new post I want to upload multiple images at the same time. Here is the code:

model.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='thumbnails')
    summary = RichTextField()
    body = RichTextUploadingField()
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_at',]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Imagens(models.Model):
    img = models.ImageField(
        upload_to = "media/",
    )
    post = models.ForeignKey(
        "Post", on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
```

admin.py

```
class ImageAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Imagens
        fields = ['img',]
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ImageAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['img'] = forms.ImageField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}))

class ImageInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Imagens
    extra = 1
    form = ImageAdminForm
  
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   search_fields = ['title']
   inlines = [ImageInline,]
   def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
     obj.save()
     files = request.FILES.getlist('img') #he gets nothing
     print(files)
     for f in files:
        x = Imagens.objects.create(post=obj,img=f)
        x.save()

admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
```

The problem is that if I save the post object it saves only one image and if I try to get the list of images it gives an empty list. Sorry I'm new to Django and even python. Every help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's just a workaround. What I did was make the main model share the form with the inlined model. So, on the change page the files appear and I'm not obliged to post the images either, but it's full of fields.

```
class ImageAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):

    imgens = forms.ImageField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        super(ImageAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['imgens'].required = False
        self.fields['img'] = forms.ImageField()
        self.fields['img'].required = False

class ImageInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Imagens
    extra = 1
    form = ImageAdminForm

class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   search_fields = ['title']
   inlines = [ImageInline]
   form = ImageAdminForm  
   def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
     obj.save()
     files = request.FILES.getlist('imgens')
     for f in files:
          x = Imagens.objects.create(post=obj,img=f)
          x.save()

admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
```